# Android Cloud Functions get data

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I'm using Firebase Cloud Functions. I'm trying to count likes on each post.
My question is actually in the Cloud functions javascript code.
I'm listening to a node in Firebase Databse Realtime that calls "likes".
Its Looks like that ->

[image]

The Tree is saved like that: PostID -> UserID -> Data

What im trying to do is to get the Data (genre and videoID) in the Cloud Functions.

**This is the code**

```
   exports.countlikechange = functions.database.ref('/likes/{postid}/{userUID}').onWrite(event => {
const collectionRef = event.data.ref.parent;
const model = event.data.val();

console.log("model",model);

 const countRef = collectionRef.child('likes');


// Return the promise from countRef.transaction() so our function 
// waits for this async event to complete before it exits.
return countRef.transaction(current => {
  if (event.data.exists() && !event.data.previous.exists()) {
    return (current || 0) + 1;
       }
  else if (!event.data.exists() && event.data.previous.exists()) {
    return (current || 0) - 1;
  }
}).then(() => {
  console.log('Counter updated.');
   });
 });
```

There is anyway to get the genre and videoId from the node?
what should i write?
for example: const genre = event.getGenre (something like that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `genre` and `videoID` are in the `event.data` snapshot that is passed to your function. So:

```
const model = event.data.val();
let genre = model.genre;
let videoID = model.videoID;
```